# docker CPU utilization is 130%,what does it mean?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have to limit my container to use only 1 CPU and 3GB memory,So I used the command:

> docker run -it -d -p 9090:9090 myImage1.4 --cpus="0.5" --memory=3Gb

When I do **docker stats b8e00adbba34**        , it gives me the below result:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O             PIDS
b8e00adbba34        0.66%               1.979 GiB / 7.632 GiB   25.93%              1.695 MB / 4.415 MB   223.5 MB / 7.799 MB   0
```

And my **docker info** is:

```
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.632 GiB
```

My problem is that although I am limiting my memory to 3GB why is it coming as 7.6 GB(host RAM),and CPU% going above 100% ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing those arguments to your image which probably is not doing anything of it. You need to pass them to docker

```
docker run -it -d -p 9090:9090 myImage1.4 --cpus="0.5" --memory=3G
```

should be (older docker versions)

```
docker run -it --cpu-quota=50000 --memory=3G -d -p 9090:9090  myImage1.4
```

or (newer docker versions)

```
docker run -it --cpus="0.5" --memory=3G -d -p 9090:9090  myImage1.4
```

Comment: your `docker version`?

Comment: 1.12.6,Instead of --cpus I tried with --cpu-quota=50000,and it works

Comment: `--cpus` came in later version of docker. I think `17.04+`, not sure of the exact version

Comment: When I run it as docker run -it --cpus="0.5" --memory=1.5Gb -d -p 9090:9090  myImage1.4,why does it give error
/usr/bin/docker-current: invalid size: '1.5Gb'.

Comment: It should be `1.5G` and not `GB`. `Memory limit (format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g. Minimum is 4M.`

Comment: /usr/bin/docker-current: invalid size: '1.5G'.The thing is I see that it is not taking fractions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155391/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-shadab).